# Python Thread Not Starting

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

Mashing code from a few different sources I am trying to make a python chat client. I can connect to the server but I want to use two threads so I can send and recieve messages at the same time. I am new to python and cannot get my threads to work. My python version is 2.7.5

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket
import time
import threading

# Define a function for the thread
def sendChat( socket, name):
    userInput = ""
    while userInput != "exit":
        userInput = raw_input("What do you want to say")
        userInput = (userInput+'\r\n')
        socket.send(userInput)
    socket.close

print "Hello, Python!"

userName = raw_input("What would you like your user name to be:")
print (userName + " welcome to chatclient, connecting to server now...")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 4444
s.connect((host, port))
print "... connected to server!"
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( sendChat, (s, "sendChat" ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

time.sleep(100)
```

Here is what I get when I run it:

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:network ryan$ python chatclient.py
Hello, Python!
What would you like your user name to be:ryan
ryan welcome to chatclient, connecting to server now...
... connected to server!
Error: unable to start thread
```

I have seen that the main thread can end before the new one so I tried add the sleep at the end but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with the code exactly as given, your catch-all `try/except` is hiding the obvious cause.  If I remove the `try/except`, I get:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "ga.py", line 26, in <module>
>     thread.start_new_thread( sendChat, (s, "sendChat" ) )
> NameError: name 'thread' is not defined
> ```

Obvious, yes?  You didn't import the `thread` module, so of course calling `thread.start_new_thread()` can't possibly work (you imported `threading` instead - which you *should* be using instead of the low-level `thread` module).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you actually running the code and literally finding my problem for me.

Comment: Don't get optimistic too fast - you'll find more problems as you go on ;-)

Comment: Yup, now I am having trouble with the server thread portions in Java, but I am sure I can figure this one out.